# How to close Teamviewer automatically?

Tags: scripts, teamviewer

I can launch Teamviewer from a script. I can start/stop/restart the daemon, also. But, how do I **close** down the app window automatically (whether it be from a script, crontab, whatever)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the terminal code and you can use it as script.

```
xdotool search "teamviewer" windowactivate --sync
xdotool key alt+F4
```

that will close the team-viewer.